# Find distinct categories of products

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, hiveql

I have been asked to find the distinct categories of products but the problem is that the table category_code has value in this format 'category.sub_category.product'. Now my question is that how can I find a distinct category with values in such format?

Answer (score 0):

Use split function to get category_code splitted using dot as a delimiter into an array(category,sub_category,product), then get element[0] for category:

```
select distinct split(category_code,'\\.')[0] as category
  from your table
```